# How close to being well-orderable does this make my powerset?

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory, axiom-of-choice

Let's work in a set theory without assuming AC (for instance, but not necessarily, ZF). Fix a set $k$ satisfying $k\times k \simeq k$, and consider its powerset $X = 2^k$. I have a technical condition that is satisfied whenever $X$ is well-orderable, but I can't tell what other examples there might be. Excuse the peculiar phrasing: I'm aiming for the most constructive means possible (by "well-orderable" I mean classically so: a total order such that every inhabited subset has a least element. This is equivalent to $X$ being a [choice object](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/choice+object)).

Let $p\colon X \to I$ be a partition of $X$ into subsets $X_i=p^{-1}(i)\lt X$, $i\in I$ such that the images of all functions $f_i\colon X_i \to X$ have inhabited complement $\forall i \in I$. Assume I is minimal in the $\lt$-ordering of sets by cardinality (if $X$ is well-orderable, then $I$ is unique and $I\simeq cf(X)$). The condition is as follows:

> For all partitions as just described, and all families of functions $(f_i\colon X_i \to X\mid i \in I)$, the surjection
>   $$
>   \coprod_{i\in I} X_i \setminus f_i(X_i) \to I
> $$
>   has a section.

The consequence of this that I want is that I can choose a point in the complement of every map $X \to X^I$, namely $X < X^I$. For well-orderable $X$ this is a corollary of a restriction of König's theorem to powers of well-orderable sets in place of arbitrary products of families.

I would like to know if there are examples that aren't well-orderable, or otherwise how close to be able to well-order $X$ this gets. Note in particular, that we could take every function $f_i$ to be constant at a fixed point $x\in X$, and so this case implies that we should be able to take a section of $X\setminus\lbrace x\rbrace \to I$ and hence of $p$, for $p$ and $I$ as above.

Note that I don't quite have the result that $X$ is a choice object (equivalently, classically well-orderable). I'm not demanding the existence of sections for arbitrary surjections, or more generally for total relation into $X$ (a fine distinction, I'm sure).

**Edit:** $X$ being a choice object is equivalent to saying that there is a choice function from the set $P_+X$ of inhabited subsets to $X$. I am only asking for a choice function on the subset of $P_+X$ given by those subsets of $X$ of strictly smaller cardinality, call it $P^{\lt X}_+X$.

Comment: I would also be happy assuming that $k$ is regular, in the sense that if given a partition $k to J$ with properties as above, and $J$ is minimal, then $k \simeq J$

Comment: Do you want this to be true for all such $p:X\to I$, or only for some such $p:X\to I$?

Comment: No, just the ones satisfying the conditions as given before the grey box. If it were for all $p$, then clearly I get a choice object.

Comment: Er, that's what I meant by "such".

Comment: My mistake! I really need to get some sleep, I didn't see the 'such'. Yes, all such. Also since the existence of an object that is choice and with two elements implies classical logic, I do wonder whether my condition forces classical logic too.

Comment: Are you also assuming $X_i < X$?

Comment: Ah, @FrançoisG.Dorais, yes! I forgot to write it...but I did mention it's related to cofinality in special cases :-S

Comment: I am confused by your question. Do you mean $X\setminus f_i(X_i)$ in the grey box, rather than $X_i\setminus f_i(X_i)$?

Comment: And the consequence that you mention, $X<X^I$, isn't it equivalent to the condition you intend to state? So you want an example of a non-well-ordered $X$ where $X<X^I$, where $I$ is a cofinality of $X$, right?

Comment: The reals in the Feferman-Levy model, for example, is not an example like that, since in this model, the reals are a countable union of countable sets, so $\omega$ is a cofinality of $\mathbb{R}$ in that model, but $\mathbb{R}$ is bijective with $\mathbb{R}^\omega$ in ZF, without using AC.

Comment: Is it known whether $\mathbb{R}$ can be non-well-orderable, but still regular? That is, regular in the sense that it is not the union of a smaller-than-$\mathbb{R}$ collection of smaller-than-$\mathbb{R}$-sized sets? If so, then this would be an example, since $\mathbb{R}<\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}}$ is always true, even without AC.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins you're right on the condition in the box, and that it's equivalent to the desired consequence. But I think the phrasing in terms of choice functions may be helpful. And yes, a non-well ordered X, or a reason it must be well-orderable is what I'm after.

Comment: I suppose that you're not interested in the case of a set $X$ without a cofinality---so that there is no such minimal $I$---although it seems that this would vacuously satisfy your condition (and could not be well-ordered).

Comment: Or could you clarify:  do you want $I$ to be fixed, while you consider all partitions $X_i$ for $i\in I$ with $X_i<X$, or is your condition that $X<X^I$ for all $I$ that are minimal such that there is a partition? I believe that without AC, a set $X$ can have several different (incomparable) cofinalities $I$, or none.

Comment: @Joel: The regularity of $\Bbb R$ should follow from DC+Perfect Set Property. In such a situation any cardinal strictly less than $2^{\aleph_0}$ is countable, and DC ensures that countable unions of countable sets are countable. So in Solovay's model and in models of AD this should be true (AD might not prove DC, but it gives us enough countable choice for this matter, namely countable choice for sets of reals).

Comment: @AsafKaragila That's great! But could you explain why does $I$ have to be $\leq\mathbb{R}$ in those models? Without AC, can't a cofinality of a set be incomparable with the set?

Comment: @Joel: You wrote "Less-than-$\Bbb R$". But I think you can just show directly that any function to the ordinals must have at least one uncountable fiber. So the only way to partition the reals into small sets is to partition them into exactly continuum many sets.

Comment: @AsafKaragila But we don't assume $I$ is well-ordered here; rather, it is just a cofinality, which means that it is minimal such that $\mathbb{R}$ has a partition into $I$ many sets, each of size less than $\mathbb{R}$. Can it be incomparable with $\mathbb{R}$? And while I have you, what can you say about the consistency with ZF that a set has more than one cofinality?

Comment: @Joel: Right, but $\{\omega_1,\frak c\}$ is a maximal antichain of cardinals. So any partition of $\Bbb R$ is either comparable with $\omega_1$ and therefore has an uncountable part (and therefore a part of size continuum), or must have exactly $2^{\aleph_0}$ parts.

Comment: @Joel: While you have me, I have thought about these questions before and never really got anywhere with actually doing something about them. But in all likelihood this is not terribly difficult to arrange (e.g. Russell socks' or something even slightly more complex than that). So as far as things are concerned, I never even managed to convince myself what is the right definition of a cofinality and regularity anyway (minimal? minimum? supremum of "too small to be cofinality"? infinimum of "too large to be cofinality"?).

Comment: @AsafKaragila Good points---although I was hoping you'd have a sweeping explanation. Regarding your argument, though, why do the partitions of $\mathbb{R}$ in this model into $\omega_1$ pieces must involve an uncountable piece? If all the piecs are countable, you can't seem to choose the witnessing enumerations without $\omega_1$-AC.

Comment: @Joel: Admittedly, this part I'm a bit fuzzy on, but I am going on a gut feeling here. I'll try to find a more mathematical reason later this evening.

Comment: @Joel: I think you might correct here. Using an argument similar to the Feferman-Levy construction that the reals is a countable union of countable sets, you should be able to show that the reals in the Solovay model is the $\aleph_1$-union of countable sets. Simply let $A_\alpha$ be the set of all names for reals with support bounded below $\alpha$, then by adding sufficiently large collapse you have made $A_\alpha$ countable. But every real appears in one of the $A_\alpha$'s, and the sequence itself is also stable and of length $\kappa$ which is now $\omega_1$. And so the result follows.

Comment: @Joel: Interestingly enough, this should also holds in Truss' model. There, however, $\omega_1$ is singular. But at the same time, the countable union of countable sets of reals is countable. So $\omega$ is *not* a cofinality of $\frak c$. So you actually get this *really weird* situation where cofinality can be singular. Moreover, if you require that the cofinality is in fact $\leq^*$-minimal, then in both cases (Solovay and Truss) $\operatorname{cf}(\mathfrak c)=\omega_1$.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins $I$ can be anything. I wrote 'minimal', because I thought that cardinality, even without choice, was a well-founded preorder (say using <), but you'd know better than me. But I don't necessarily need to assume $I$ in any way minimal.

Comment: @AsafKaragila thanks for these interesting comments! Perhaps the comments section here is not the best place, so perhaps your blog, when you write that post you (privately) promised, would be better?

Comment: @Joel, David: The blog post is up. I'd link it here, but there is a link to this post and I don't want to create a non-well founded chain of links. :-)

Comment: @AsafKaragila if it is consistent that every non-well-orderable set has cofinality 2, then this is a good answer to add below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prompted by the discussion in comments above, Asaf wrote a blog post [Cofinality and the axiom of choice](http://karagila.org/2015/cofinality-and-the-axiom-of-choice/) that gave the following example of a model of ZF:

> It is consistent that every non well-orderable set has cofinality 2. This was shown by Monro (“[Decomposable Cardinals](https://eudml.org/doc/214599)“, Fund. Math. vol. 80 (1973), no. 2, 101–104.), more specifically the real numbers can have cofinality 2.

This destroys the inequality $\kappa < 2^{cf(\kappa)}$ resulting from König's theorem (I like to call this inequality *König's corollary*), for the notion of cofinality in the original question.